# What is a good translation of "cancelled" in the context of buses and trains?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm looking for a good translation for *cancelled* in the context of transportation. As in

> X bus line has been cancelled.

Comment: Do you mean a single bus that's not running today, or the whole line becoming inoperational?

Comment: Informally and for flights in particular, one may use _cancel_ as a loan word, though the spelling can be awkward or difficult: _Der Flug ist/wurde gecancelt/*gekänzelt._

Comment: @Crissov I think _annulieren_ would work better there. _Der Flug ist annuliert worden._

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The common verb to describe that a train/bus/plane is cancelled is *ausfallen*, in your example

> Buslinie X fällt aus.

Comment: Or "bleibt aus"? I think it should be ok that way as well.

Comment: The Austrian railways ÖBB usually use "Zug Nr. ... kann heute nicht in Verkehr gesetzt werden."

Comment: Deutsche Bahn says "ICE 611 nach ... entfällt heute". Ein Flug dagegen wird *gestrichen*.

Comment: In case of Deutsche Bahn you call this "standard". ;)

Answer (score 26):

If the bus line simply ceased to exist, the translation would be

> Die Buslinie X wurde eingestellt.

If there is is only a temporary obstacle, like an accident, I propose

> Der Betrieb (auf) der Buslinie wurde (beispielsweise: für zwei Stunden) eingestellt.

For trains, which have more of an identity than buses as for flights typical phrase is:

> Der Zug (ICE 801 or whatever its number) entfällt.

Depending on the context one could replace *entfällt* by *wurde gestrichen* if you need to emphasize the active part in the context as in *wurde von der Fluglinie xy gestrichen*.

Comment: "für zwei Stunden einstellen" sounds weird. "Einstellen" isn't quite a temporary thing, to my mind, but rather permanent. If it's temporary used, though, it's normally way longer than two hours (a year, e.g.). For short term cancellation,  "vorrübergehend/für zwei Stunden ausfallen" seems better. Anyhow, +1 for also mentioning "ceasing to exist".

Comment: "Der Betrieb wurde für zwei Stunden _ausgesetzt_."

Comment: Die Idee all diese Begriffe zu vereinheitlichen, indem sie durch "GDL" ersetzt werden, konnte sich in der Bevölkerung noch nicht durchsetzten - trotz größter öffentlichkeitswirksamer Bemühungen der gleichnamigen Organisation.

Comment: Indeed both version "Bus X gestrichen" oder "Bus X entfällt" are the best translations. "Eingestellt" is rather used for a permanent cancellation while the others are more temporarily.